# Changing field length when foreign keys reference primary key field in table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a situation where a number of foreign keys are referencing a column in Table "A". I would like to change the length of the column in table "A". What is the best way to accomplish this in SQL Server 2008 R2? I am really hoping I don't have to drop all 30 foreign key constraints and re-create them again...

Comment: Why do you need `ilastic` field lengths? There's a max length anyway allowed for a field. At the point of designing, would have set to `max`...

Comment: bonCodigo -- hindsight is 20/20... But this is a situation I am facing now.

Comment: and (b) primary key fields can't be varchar(max)

Comment: There you go the answer ;) Summarize my comments.

Comment: @bonCodigo - See [varchar(max) everywhere?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2091284) for some reasons why that is *not* a good idea.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks, so in terms of indices, `varchar(max)` a downside. Since Denis has to anyway `drop` all and `create` from the scratch, then there's no need to have max length. I pointed out max, coz he said "he is really hoping he doesn't have to drop all" and star from *square 1* ;)

Comment: @bonCodigo - Not just because the column itself can't be indexed but memory consumption, blocks online index rebuilds in < 2012, if using row compression it won't be compressed, can prevent an optimisation where versioning tags aren't added if the table has a trigger, can mean locks are held longer, possibly other miscellaneous downsides as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Script out Drop and Create All 30 JF.
2. Drop all 30 KF
3. Alter Columns
4. Create all 30 KF

Comment: can't I disable all the foreign keys somehow?

Comment: there is no disable option in MSSQL

Comment: ugh... was hoping I didn't have to do it... I have to teach my users to abbreviate :-)

Comment: There is a way you can disable foreign keys on tables: ALTER TABLE TableName NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL. This however won't help when altering primary key/unique constraint columns, but it's useful information.

Comment: @fortheworld - tried that. That only disable the constraints for operations like INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE. Doesn't disable the constraints when you are changing field lengths.

Answer (score 2):

You can change column length in TableA via GUI (Management Studio), and all the foreign keys will be changed automatically.

Comment: Good for small things that aren't critical but I just had this delete one of my main tables and not restore it when it timed out creating foreign keys through the diagram editor.